# Cohomology of cocompact lattices in hyperbolic spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology, lattices, arithmetic-groups

I have a (maybe too naive) hope that cocompact torsion-free arithmetic lattices in hyperbolic spaces $X \neq \mathbb{H}_\mathbb{R}^2$ are uniquely determined by their cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. I was wondering if there are any known counter examples to this claim, that is:

**Question**: Are there torsion free cocompact lattices of hyperbolic spaces (real, complex or quaternionic of dimension $\geq 3$) that are not isomorphic but have the same cohomolgy?

Comment: They can even be homology spheres or homology projective planes.

Comment: Thank you! I see that my first question was a silly one then...

Comment: Maybe you want to also exclude a bit more (e.g. very small dimension?). Also you need to specify whether you mean cohomology as graded abelian group, or as graded algebra (which retains more information).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean with "the same cohomology". If you don't care about the multiplicative structure and work on $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, then you are asking whether the collection of Betti numbers determine the lattice, right?

I would then say that the answer is no (and this goes in the same direction as the comment by Moishe Kohan): in PU(2,1), there are examples of cocompact torsion free lattices which have the same Betti numbers as $\mathbb{CP}^2$. The corresponding quotients of the unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ are called "fake projective planes" (see the first example by Mumford, and the more recent classification by Prasad--Yeung).

There are several such lattices which are non-isomorphic, thus answering negatively your question (in the "weak" setting I described).

Comment: OP considers $\mathbf{Z}$-coefficients, so keeps track of torsion therein. Thus this is more than just Betti numbers.

Comment: According to this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05291.pdf), there are two that have H_1 = Z/7Z.

Comment: Even with the multiplicative structure, integer (co)homology spheres (of which there are many with real hyperbolic structures) show that the answer is “no”.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that the rational cohomology would be too weak, but it is always nice to see concrete examples where things go wrong